# What web framework provides automatic database scaffolding based on table relations and foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, web-applications, scaffolding

I [hypothetically] have three tables, with columns as follows:

- items: item_id, description, cost
- orders: order_id, name
- order_items: order_id, item_id, quantity

I have defined the obvious foreign keys. In the desktop application "Sequel Pro" this is enough information so that when I am viewing the order_items table every entry in the order_id and item_id columns includes a link to the appropriate row in the orders and items tables ([screenshot of a different example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RCfD.png)). That is the bare minimum functionality that I am looking for in a web based framework for building an interface to browse my database. Manually writing queries to create those links would be a duplication of information, because the schema by which the tables should be connected is already described in the table relations.

More generally, I would like for it to be able to edit and add to the database, and to provide links/queries in the opposite direction[1] or even include information inline[2].

Does any such framework exist? MS Access does things like this, but it's not web based, and generally not awesome for non-Access DBs anyway.

[1] As mentioned above, I already get links from order_items.order_id to the appropriate single row in orders. What I'd like in reverse is a link from orders.order_id that produces a list of all the rows in order_items with that order_id.

[2] It should not require any custom query writing to specify that for a one-to-one relationship, such as order_items to items, I just want the contents of the items row displayed inline when viewing the order_items table, instead of having to click through / drill down to it. Even better would be if this worked for one-to-many relationships as well, so that I could click on a single row in the orders table to see all the matching order_items AND the relevant data from items inline with each of those.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the language you feel confortable with, you can try:

- Spring MVC
- Grails http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html
- Ruby on Rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.9/getting_started.html

perhaps the latters have a gentle learning curve

e.g In Grails (as in other ORM based framework) you should first generate your domain classes representing your db tables and describing their relationship. 
Actually, you don't have to manually write those down, you can adopt a reverse engineering plugin, like http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/docs/manual/guide/single.html which will use your DB schema to generate entities.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how any of these would be directly relevant? It looks like with Grails or RoR (or any MVC scaffold system I've encountered) I would need to re-describe all of my table relationships as part of a Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I did this same search about a year ago. I had many related tables (one-to-one and one-to-many). I ended up using CI Bonfire (http://cibonfire.com/) and then enhanced the code build process to support related data. My forked version is on github at https://github.com/wescleveland56/Bonfire/tree/feature/enhanced-build-parent-child. I'm pretty github ignorant, and haven't followed the development since this fork. But maybe it's what you're looking for.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use Symfony2 or Symfony1.4 for the same ..

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [cakePhp](http://cakephp.org/) , if interested to use Php. It provides very easy and efficient scaffolding just by using a keyword: **public $scaffold;**  and the work is done.

Comment: This still sounds like it requires my db relationships to be recreated in the cakePHP Model framework. Let me be clear: I do not want to specify my table relationships in multiple places, and I've already specified them as foreign keys in the sql schema.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP provides an automagic scaffolding, if the database layer was designed as per cakePHP's convention, this automagic scaffolding is very basic, next thing which cakePHP provides is generation of Model/Views/and controllers in CLI mode, which is very interactive, one can create a complete CRUD application using this feature.

Yii provides a web based interface for generating MVC based CRUD application from a relational database, this framework is considered as one of the fastest MVC framework (at least in current time).

You can use any of these two, but remember since you are expecting scaffolding you will have to follow some conventions as expected from these frameworks.

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, applications such as Sequel Pro can do the "scaffolding" job without any convention-following outside of SQL standards. My database already exists, and other applications depend on it. I am not in a position to change the database to suit this task.